# How to develop Spotify Desktop Applications, now Libspotify is discontinued

Tags: spotify, libspotify

have done my due diligence, and not found any other posts that answer this question, but as usual, if you know a similar question, point me that way!

I noticed a long time back that Libspotify has been dicontinued:

[image: Libspotify deprecated notice]
[image: Libspotify removal notice]

(https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/)

So, my question is - what should we do for developing Desktop applications?

They do state: "We hope to be able to provide you with a new library for other platforms." But, this has been going on since 2015!

I have seen many projects in GitHub still using Libspotify - so what should we do? An update was promised "in the upcoming months" but I've not seen anything yet.

Comment: Could you let me know where an update was promised? I want to make sure our developer resources are clear.

Comment: In the screenshot I included above it states : "More information regarding upcoming libraries will be provided in the coming months". As of this posting that statement is still at https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/, so thats AT LEAST(!) from March until August - which I would define as "coming months" ;)

Answer (score 0):

> What should we do for developing Desktop Applications?

We at Spotify don't currently provide playback as part of our platform offering outside of our [iOS](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) and [Android](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/) SDKs, and I don't have any updates on that at the moment. As mentioned on the website, we hope to be able to provide playback SDKs for more platforms in the future. We don't support any new development on libspotify.

You can use the [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) to interact with Spotify in a variety of ways, including getting information about metadata, and accessing/modifying user libraries and playlists, which may be useful. You can also use the [Applescript API](https://developer.spotify.com/applescript-api/) to control playback on macOS, which may also help.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. Some clarifications though: "We at Spotify don't currently provide playback as part of our platform offering outside of our iOS and Android SDKs" - does this mean, LibSpotify can not be used at all anymore? If I were to fork a project that uses LibSpotify is that ok? Of course, an application key is the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's right, as [noted on our site](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/), libspotify is completely unsupported.

Comment: So how would you make a Spotify remote now for Desktops? It's not possible?

Comment: @dezza: to make a remote desktop app, you could use the [Spotify connect APIs](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-connect-endpoint-reference/) to control playback remotely :)

Comment: @Rawlinson thats where the fun stops the "streaming" scope which controls playback is only for android/ios at the moment: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/ I just get a permission denied using /next for skipping track

Comment: Yep, the streaming scope is for android and iOS - but you can use the web APIs I linked to to control playback on many devices for premium users, so you can develop a remote app using those. Full playback is only available using the Android and iOS SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

The Spotify Web API is pretty straight forward to use. Of course it defines the protocol rather than implements it so it is OS independent.

I put together a few classes to help unwrap some of the JSON parameters simply. These were written in Swift for macOS.

Comment: Mark, yeah that's true; my concern is the web API is not complete enough to make a desktop class application

Comment: Interesting. What do you consider is missing?

Comment: Hi mark! Sorry it's been a while! I'm happy to be proven wrong (if I've misread the docs) but my understanding was that the playback APis are only available for iOS (perhaps android?!) but not in the web.